# how to insert new column and sum(), and make increase, decrase notif in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

i've data frame(df in pandas) below:

```
sector   Income Januari 2018     Income januari 2019     
1                  2000                    3000                  
1                  7000                    1000
```

and i want to insert new column with sum()

so my expected:

```
sector   Income Januari 2018     Income januari 2019   increase▲/decrease▼
1                  2000                    3000           1000 ▲ (green)         
1                  7000                    1000           6000 ▼ (red)
```

Comment: check diff ? negative is decrease positive is increase

Comment: Yes, based on sum (income januari 2019 - income januari 2018)

Comment: @WeNYoBen Lol, it was a pain to deal with those strange characters lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set background color by styles and [export to excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel):

```
def color(x): 
   c1 = 'background-color: green'
   c2 = 'background-color: red'
   c = ''
   m = x['Income januari 2019'] > x['Income Januari 2018']
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
   df1['increase▲/decrease▼'] = np.where(m, c1, c2)
   return df1

df['increase▲/decrease▼'] = df['Income januari 2019'] - df['Income Januari 2018']
print (df)
   sector  Income Januari 2018  Income januari 2019  increase▲/decrease▼
0       1                 2000                 3000                 1000
1       1                 7000                 1000                -6000

df.style.apply(color,axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

If need absolute values in output column add [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
df['increase▲/decrease▼'] = (df['Income januari 2019'] - df['Income Januari 2018']).abs()
print (df)
   sector  Income Januari 2018  Income januari 2019  increase▲/decrease▼
0       1                 2000                 3000                 1000
1       1                 7000                 1000                 6000
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, it works but i edited a little bit in your script - - > df['increase▲/decrease▼'] = (df['Income januari 2019'] - df['Income Januari 2018']).apply(lambda x: '%s ▲' % x if x > 0 else '%s ▼' % -x), because i need ▼▲ , for every row,  so i have a question, can i add color on my character (▼▲)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below line of code:

```
df['increase▲/decrease▼'] = (df['Income januari 2019'] - df['Income Januari 2018']).apply(lambda x: '%s ▲' % x if x > 0 else '%s ▼' % -x)
```

Output would be as expected.

Comment: @Income Januari 2019 it works, but can you show me to add the color?
(green for ▲ ) and  (red for ▼ )

Comment: sorry sir on your program if the difference is 0, it will ( 0▼). what if 0 so ther's no special character